# find out when public IP changes (monitor network settings)

Tags: linux

I want to create a simple script that informs me (by sending an email) when my public IP address changed. (So something similar to what dyn-dns-services do).

Ok, I could create a cron job that checks my public IP every minute and if it is other than the minute before, I send the message.

But, my gateway (which the IP is assigned to) is a Debian machine, so I think there must be better solutions. Is there a well-known folder containing scripts that get executed each time the network configuration changes? Or a configuration file where I can add my script?

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically when your IP changes, your DHCP lease has expired and your client is asking the server for an extension.  The server declines and gives you a different IP instead.

The `isc-dhcp-client` package, which is probably what you are running, makes provisions to execute hooks on DHCP events.  Basically, you can put a script in `/etc/dhcp/dhclient-enter-hooks.d`, test the appropriate environment variables to make sure the interface is what you want, and the DHCP event type is what you want, and then do what you want.

Read [this](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/man8/dhclient-script.8.html) or look at `man dhclient-script` on your local system.

If you have things other than DHCP changing your IP, your method is actually a good one.

Comment: That sounds great! Thanks! I added my script to `dhclient-exit-hooks.d` but today I can't tell if it works. I have to wait until the IP changes the first time. I'll keep you up to date!

Comment: Scripts in Linux may either not have an extension or possibly something like `.sh`.  They should have their `x` bit set in the permissions though.  To run it, change to that directory and enter `./scriptname`.